# Ngx-sticky direction changed after scroll to top

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, sidebar, sticky

I use Angular Sticky makes HTML sidebar sticky.

Everything is good when I scroll to down of page, but when I scroll to the top direction of sidebar changed and goes to right side of the page.

I use angular 6.0.2 and angular material 6.0.1;

github [Ngx-sticky](https://github.com/makseo/ng2-sticky)

Comment: Why not use `<mat-sidenav>` which is designed to do this? If you are referring to some third-party component called `ngx-sticky`, please provide a link to it. But since not that many people here probably know of `ngx-sticky`, you probably would be better off posting an issue on their github page.

Comment: i want to use sticky position for fixed detail during scroling page